# Spliting a column with strings in a dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, delimiter

I have the following dataframe imported from a csv file:

```
ts  employee_id gps_lat gps_lng event_id    event_params    speed   status  serial_number
9/22/2016 13:53 1   34.97   -81.98  Down    {"type":"Down","maximumangle":0,"duration":0}   0   1100110 211
9/22/2016 13:53 1   34.97   -81.98  Left    {"type":"Left","maximumangle":-38.57,"duration":203}    0   1102110 212
9/22/2016 13:53 1   34.97   -81.98  Right   {"type":"Right","maximumangle":52.975,"duration":17}    0   1102130 250
9/22/2016 13:53 1   34.97   -81.98  Down    {"type":"Down","maximumangle":0,"duration":0}   0   1102130 249
9/22/2016 13:54 1   34.97   -81.98  Down    {"type":"Down","maximumangle":0,"duration":0}   0   1102140 280
9/22/2016 13:54 1   34.97   -81.98  Left    {"type":"Left","maximumangle":-10.866,"duration":40}    0   1102140 279
```

I need to split the event_params column into separate columns with headers- Type, Maximum Angle and Duration, and I need to get rid of curly braces. In short I need the following output.

```
ts  employee_id gps_lat gps_lng event_id    Type    maximumangle    duration    speed   status  serial_number
9/22/2016 13:53 1   34.97   -81.98  Down    Down    0   0   0   1100110 211
9/22/2016 13:53 1   34.97   -81.98  Left    Left    -38.57  203 0   1102110 212
9/22/2016 13:53 1   34.97   -81.98  Right   Right   52.975  17  0   1102130 250
9/22/2016 13:53 1   34.97   -81.98  Down    Down    0   0   0   1102130 249
9/22/2016 13:54 1   34.97   -81.98  Down    Down    0   0   0   1102140 280

#Code I am trying to use:

import re
parts = re.split('\df3|(?<!\d)[:.](?!\d)', df3)
parts
```

I am trying to approach the problem by spliting it first about : delimiter, then splitting the last column by } and then deleting the columns with contents maximum angle and duration.

I have been trying to use the re.split function in the following way but it returns error

```
--expected string or bytes-like object
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it's difficult to reproduce the exact data you are working on, this solution should give you enough hint:

```
# create minimal sample data
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'employee_id':[1,2,3,4,5,6], 'gps':[1,1,1,1,1,1], 'event_params' : 
['{"type":"Down","maximumangle":0,"duration":0}',
'{"type":"Left","maximumangle":-38.57,"duration":203}',   
'{"type":"Right","maximumangle":52.975,"duration":17}', 
'{"type":"Down","maximumangle":0,"duration":0}',
'{"type":"Down","maximumangle":0,"duration":0}',
'{"type":"Left","maximumangle":-10.866,"duration":40}']})


# save event_params column to a new value while removing from df1
df2 = df1.pop('event_params')

# convert values to dictionary format using ast library
import ast
df2 = df2.apply(ast.literal_eval)

# convert dictionary to column format and add back to df1
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(df2))
df1 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)

print(df1)

  employee_id   gps     duration    maximumangle    type
0           1     1            0           0.000   Down
1           2     1          203         -38.570    Left
2           3     1           17          52.975    Right
3           4     1            0           0.000    Down
4           5     1            0           0.000    Down
5           6     1           40         -10.866    Left
```

**Edit 1:** To convert all event_params in dictionary format:

```
df2 = df2.apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x) if isinstance(x, dict) else x)
```

Comment: Also, few rows in the dataset are with a different syntax. For example:"{"maximumangle":31.495,"type":"Right","duration":16}". Thus on reaching this line of the dataset, python returns a syntax error, because its not in usual dictionary format.

Comment: by different syntax, you mean the sequence of keys in the dictionary?

Comment: No. So some rows start and end with " while some are in pure dictionary format.

{"type":"Left","maximumangle":-38.57,"duration":203}
"{"type":"Left","maximumangle":-38.57,"duration":203}"

Comment: @ashlock I've updated my answer which handles your case.

Comment: @Dear Manish, It is not working. The contents of df2 still remain in the same format.

Comment: What error are you getting ? Did you try to run the code above? Because, it works for me as expected. @ashlock

Comment: Yaa I tried running it. I am using python 3.6. I am not getting any error. Its just that df2 remains untouched as is. Following is a sample of the output I am getting. So as you can see, the last row still starts with ", while it needs to be void of that, so that everything is in dictionary format.

    {"type":"Down","maximumangle":0,"duration":0}
    {"type":"Left","maximumangle":-16.209,"duration":32}
    {"maximumangle":-12.186,"type":"Left","duration":16}
    {"maximumangle":19.648,"type":"Right","duration":13}
    "{"maximumangle":-19.169,"type":"Left","duration":10}"